# "empty_value_display" doesn't work for an empty string on "change list" page in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, string, django-models, django-admin

I defined `name` field which accepts an empty string in `Person` model as shown below. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```py
# "models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, I set `"-empty-"` to [AdminSite.empty_value_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.empty_value_display), [ModelAdmin.empty_value_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.empty_value_display), [@admin.display()'s empty_value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator) or `view_name.empty_value_display` as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

admin.site.empty_value_display = "-empty-" # Or

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("view_name",)
    empty_value_display = "-empty-" # Or

    @admin.display(empty_value="-empty-") # Or
    def view_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name

    view_name.empty_value_display = '-empty-' # Or
```

But, `-empty-` is not shown even though I saved an empty string as shown below:

[image]

So, how can I show `-empty-` when I save an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

As you found out, this only works for `None`, not for an empty string. Indeed, Django [checks this with [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/utils.py#L459-L460):

> ```
> def display_for_value(value, empty_value_display, boolean=False):
>     from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list import _boolean_icon
>
>     if boolean:
>         return _boolean_icon(value)
>     elif value is None:
>         return empty_value_display
>     # …
> ```

this thus does *not* apply to anything that has truthiness `False`, so empty strings, empty lists, `False`, etc. will *not* render the empty value.

This however does not mean that you can not make the empty string fold to `None` if necessary:

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('view_name',)

    @admin.display(empty_value='-empty-', ordering='name')
    def view_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name or None
```

this will return `None` for any value that has truthiness `False`, including the empty string, and then thus will be rendered with `-empty-`.

Answer (score 1):

[AdminSite.empty_value_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.empty_value_display), [ModelAdmin.empty_value_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.empty_value_display), [@admin.display()'s empty_value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator) or `view_name.empty_value_display` below works for a `None(Null)` value but not for an empty string:

```py
# "admin.py"

admin.site.empty_value_display = "-empty-" # Or

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("view_name",)
    empty_value_display = "-empty-" # Or

    @admin.display(empty_value="-empty-") # Or
    def view_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name

    view_name.empty_value_display = '-empty-' # Or
```

So, you need to define `name` field which accepts a `None(Null)` value in `Person` model as shown below. *You should replace `self.name` with `str(self.name)` as shown below otherwise there is an error when you save a `None(Null)` value in Django Admin:

```py
# "models.py"

class Person(models.Model):                            # Here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) # Here
```

Then, `-empty-` is shown when you save a `None(Null)` value as shown below:

[image]